# Getting all data through has many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get all the data in my table from another table depending on my title. If I do this

```
$single_portfolio = Pcategory::with('portfolio')->where('title', $title)->first();
$portfolio_title = $single_portfolio->portfolio->first()->title;
```

I only get the first item in the database. I've tried

```
$portfolio_title = $single_portfolio->portfolio->get()->title;
```

but that didn't work.

I got this error

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\bellamage-cakes\app\Modules\Open\Http\Controllers\OpenController.php on line 70 and defined

Comment: I think that's because get() returns a collection of items instead of first() returns a single item. So you may have to foreach the result with get() and then return the title of each elements.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Pcategory` and `portfolio` ? Is it oneToOne?

Answer (score 2):

I've got it. This is what I did

I changed

```
$single_portfolio = Pcategory::with('portfolio')->where('title', $title)->first();
```

to

```
$single_portfolio = Pcategory::where('title', $title)->firstOrFail();
```

and removed

```
$portfolio_title = $single_portfolio->portfolio->first()->title;
```

Then in my blade template I did this

```
@foreach($single_portfolio->portfolio as $category)
    {!! $category->title !!}
@endforeach
```

and it worked.